# defining constant values & accessing globally in zend framework 2

Tags: php, cakephp, zend-framework2

I am new to this zend2, previously I worked with CAKEPHP & codeigniter. I want to write some constant values in a particular file & be able to access them any where in the project.

In cakephp it is like `Configure::write('environment','dev');` we write this in a  file in Config folder which will be at `app/Config/file name`

and we can access this like `$env = Configure::read('environment');` any where..

Can we do in the same way in zend framework 2, like defining the constants in a file & can access them anywhere..? 
Please give an example how to define & read it with the path of the file

Answer (score 1):

No is the short answer. Cake, ZF1, CodeIgniter all made use of a design pattern, now widely discouraged, called the the [Registry Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) (which is really just a  [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)).

The very fact that this class is globally accessible, is one of the reasons why its use is not advised.

ZF2 has a completely different architecture and offers a flexible approach by [merging configuration based on environment variables](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#environment-specific-application-configuration). An when it comes to 'using' the configuration, you should be injecting it into your services using the service manager and a [service factory](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html#writing-a-factory-class).

Comment: is there a solution which could be similar to what I've asked?

Answer (score 0):

First define variable in `config`

Like:-

```
accountUser.admin = "admin"
```

Then initialize object like(in controller or model):-

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/config.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
// APPLICATION_PATH is path to project
// APPLICATION_ENV will be your environment
```

Then use it like:-

```
$admin = $config->accountUser->admin;
```

Comment: This is for ZF1, OP's question is "Can we do in the same way in zend framework 2?"